# Custom application won't start

Tags: applications, slingshot, app-shortcuts

I'm a new user in Elementary OS (0.4.1 Loki) and I find it really amazing.
But I have a problem that I cannot resolve.
I installed xampp for linux and all works fine but I wanted to put it in the plank with the others applications. Anyway, I find some tutorial and all say that I have to create the directory:

> /usr/share/applications/lampp.desktop

and put inside it [image: lampp.desktop]

Now I have the icon but when I click on it nothing appear. Seems like it's loading for a bit but nothing happen after that shot time.

I also try to replace:

> Exec=gksu ./opt ...
>
> Exec=gksudo ./opt ...
>
> Exec=./ ... (in this case no icon appear)

How can I solve it?

*I'm sorry if I say something wrong but I'm also new in Linux and still learning the basics.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you also need to specify a Path in the .desktop file. Use this image as an example.

[image]

If you need to run it as root, add `gksu` before the command:

Exec=gksu /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.sh
Path=/opt/lampp

Comment: I still don't understand why in the tutorial there wasn't the **Path** line. Thank you so much, now it works! Anyway, if I could ask, what is the difference between _sudo_ and _gksu_ in this case? Why with the first one it didn't open?

Comment: Glad it worked. Simply put, gksu displays the password prompt window, while sudo works only from Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add the menu using menulibre

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install menulibre
```

add costum menu there, and drag the menu from slingshot to plank

Answer (score 0):

I would check your exec path. You have ./opt, you should not have a . in front of your root. Could be why nothing is executing, linux can't find it.